# Close Dialog pressing button inside itself

Tags: android, dialog

I'm having troubles with this. when you click a item a dialogue appears showing the content in `"cambiar.xml"`, I want to close the dialogue when pressing "OK" or "Borrar", I tried everything but i can`t, here is the code!

```
public class Iniciado extends Activity{

TextView tv3;
ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.iniciado);
    tv3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv3);
    Bundle bolsar = getIntent().getExtras();
    tv3.setText("Bienvenido "+ bolsar.getString("NombreKey"));

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Defined Array values to show in ListView
    String[] values = new String[] { "Android List View", 
                                     "Adapter implementation",
                                     "Simple List View In Android",
                                     "Create List View Android", 
                                     "Android Example", 
                                     "List View Source Code", 
                                     "List View Array Adapter", 
                                     "Android Example List View" 
                                    };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);


          // Assign adapter to ListView
          listView.setAdapter(adapter); 

          // ListView Item Click Listener
          listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                 // ListView Clicked item index
                 int itemPosition     = position;

                 // ListView Clicked item value
                 String  itemValue    = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                  // Show Alert 
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Position :"+itemPosition+"  ListItem : " +itemValue , Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

                  Dialog d = new Dialog(Iniciado.this);
                  d.setTitle("Editar evento");
                  d.setContentView(R.layout.cambiar);
                  d.show();

                }


           }); 
}
```

Sorry for my english, and thanks!

I finnaly solved it, here is the code of the class who has the button that open the dialog!

```
package com.example.iniciosesion;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Iniciado extends Activity {

    TextView tv3;
    ListView listView;
    final Context context = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.iniciado);
        tv3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv3);
        Bundle bolsar = getIntent().getExtras();
        tv3.setText("Bienvenido "+ bolsar.getString("NombreKey"));
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Defined Array values to show in ListView
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android List View", 
                                         "Adapter implementation",
                                         "Simple List View In Android",
                                         "Create List View Android", 
                                         "Android Example", 
                                         "List View Source Code", 
                                         "List View Array Adapter", 
                                         "Android Example List View" 
                                        };

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);


              // Assign adapter to ListView
              listView.setAdapter(adapter); 

              // ListView Item Click Listener
              listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                     // ListView Clicked item index
                     int itemPosition     = position;

                     // ListView Clicked item value
                     String  itemValue    = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                      // Show Alert 
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Position :"+itemPosition+"  ListItem : " +itemValue , Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

                      // Make Dialog                

                        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.cambiar);
                        dialog.setTitle("Title...");

                        // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
                        EditText editar = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.eteditar);

                        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.okbtn);
                        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });

                        dialog.show();

                   }
           });

      }


    }
```

and here is the code of the dialog layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/eteditar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </EditText>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/eteditar" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/okbtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="OK" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/borrarbtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Borrar" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you will need to initilize both buttons from Dialog layout to perform actions on Button click which is inside Dialog layout as:

```
 Button btn_OK = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.dialog_btn_ok);

 btn_OK.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // close Dialog here
                d.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

do same for `Borrar` button also